# QThread, creating GUI widget element on a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I've been trying that for a while and seems it's not something common as I didn't find much information about.

I have a QTree in which I put item, on my Item i have a check box on the first column.

Problem: Checkbox is not optimised to be treated as so and takes quite some time as soon as there is several elements.

So i'm using a thread to create the checkbox before putting in my list, but seems impossible to get the checkbox back on the GUI thread.

```
void CheckItemThread::run()
{
    setPriority(QThread::IdlePriority);
    QCheckBox     *m_check;
    m_check = new QCheckBox();
    emit done(m_check);
}
```

My main thread:

```
myCheckItem::myCheckItem(QTreeWidget *parent, QStringList columnNames ):
  myWidgetItem(parent)
{
  m_parent = parent;
  m_columnNames = columnNames;

    connect(&TheThread,SIGNAL(done(QCheckBox *)), this, SLOT(retThread(QCheckBox *)));
    connect(&TheThread,SIGNAL(terminated()), this, SLOT(endThread()));
    TheThread.setdata(columnNames,parent, this);
    TheThread.start();    //run thread
}
    void myCheckItem::endThread()
    {
        m_check->setParent(m_parent);
        connect(m_check, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onCheckBox(int)));
    }

void myCheckItem::retThread(QCheckBox *check)
{
    m_check = check;
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something or it's simple not possible to reattach the thread ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you really need to create a widget on a thread? isn't it easier to create the data you need in the thread and signal the gui that back-end data is ready and can be used to create the new ui that is needed?

Comment: It's not the treatment of the data that takes time but the creation of the checkbox : m_check = new QCheckBox();

Comment: what do you do once you have created the checkbox? you add it to the treewidget??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must not** create, edit or work with UI elements in other threads. UI elements must be worked with in the main thread (UI thread). If you have time-consuming prerequisites before "drawing" a checkbox, do your work in a thread (eventually `QtConcurrent`) and send a signal to the main thread for creating the corresponding checkbox.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the creation of the checkbox itself that is taking a long time. m_check = new QCheckBox(); Basically creating the element on the thread work but then the thread won't stop.

Comment: The object resides in its creation thread, therefor m_check will still be in the client thread. You definitly should not do this. You can move object with moveToThread(), but this is not intented for GUI elements. If you do have a large amount of checkboxes then really think about keeping them static in a pool and reuse them. Since you are using them in an tree-element, try reimplementing QAbstractItemDelegate so the listitem itself would handle creation. This may get you a small push, but do not expect to much of it.

Comment: I understand your point, it seems i do not have threadable solution here, although I have some memories that a thread can be reattached, maybe was on linux?. Creating a pool of checkbox will require a lot of modification on the code.

Comment: @SebastianLange It's not only you must not, it's that **you can not perform GUI operations in a thread different from main thread**, also called GUI-thread which.

 http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-starting.html#starting-a-thread

Comment: @Damien, consider to use `QTreeView` instead of `QTreeWidget`, it will do all the work with creating and reusing the checkboxes for you

Answer (score 0):

You can change GUI elements only in main thread. How many checkboxes do you have? Maybe you should create a limited count of checkboxes and reuse them when needed?

Comment: My checkbox are on a list, might be more than 200. they are updated with the list.

Comment: How much time consumes creating of 200 QCheckBoxes? Anyway, you can use QTreeView instead of QTreeWidget, it can create checkboxes by itself, letting you not to think about performance.